# peek syntax and usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am writing my own program using `peek` and this is what I have:

```
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as inpf2:
    while True:
            c = [inpf2.read(1)]
            if not c:
                break
            k = c.peek(2)
            for d in k:
                if(d == ""):
                    break
                else:
                    c = c.append(d)
            print c
```

In this program, i am using `peek` to see ahead 2 characters in a text file which has text like `abcdefg` and trying to print out strings of 3 characters like `abc`, `bcd`, `cde`, `def`, `efg`.

But when I execute this program, i am getting the error,

```
k = c.peek(2)  
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'peek'.
```

Where am I doing a mistake?

Comment: You might want to use more descriptive names. I don't know what `k` or `inpf` are supposed to mean (though one can guess in context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Python object having a `peek` method (apart from [`io.BufferedStream`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html?highlight=peek#io.BufferedReader.peek), that's the only method returned from a search in the docs).

I'm afraid you'd have to define a `peek` function yourself. You can find a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577361-peek-ahead-an-iterator/) online that could get you started.

For your particular problem, maybe you could consider using [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=peek#collections.deque)

Answer (score 2):

I came here wondering about this, and then it hit me: `peek` is simply `list[-1]`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to peek ahead, remember the characters you've already seen. That is, don't print the current character and the next two characters, print the current character and the *last* two.

```
from collections import deque

with open('temp.txt') as infile:
    window = deque(infile.read(2), maxlen=3)
    nextchar = infile.read(1)
    while nextchar:
        window.append(nextchar)
        print "".join(window)
        nextchar = infile.read(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a list, so you're trying to `peek` on a list. At the very least, you have to call `peek` on the first element in the list, so something like `c[0].peek()`

But even then, you're filling `c` with the data in the file, so you'd really want to call `peek` on your file object instead of the returned data, like so: `k = inpf2.peek(2)`